# Chrome 65 - unable to make POST requests from local files to Flask

Tags: ajax, google-chrome, post, flask, cors

I'm running the following code:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

@app.route('/test', methods=['POST'])
def test():
    return jsonify({'result': 'hello'}), 201

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```

Upon trying to open the following page, I am presented with the error message:

> The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'null' that is
>   not equal to the supplied origin. Origin 'null' is therefore not
>   allowed access.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
  function func() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "http://0.0.0.0:5000/test",
      method: "POST",
      contentType: "application/json"
    });
  }
  window.onload = func
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This doesn't occur with Chrome 64. Does anyone know why this is?

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution not requiring mounting your local file in a web server could be done by allowing cross-origin via CORS. (usefull if you need several local files - e.g. linking javascript/css files).

Just replace the line:

> CORS(app)

by

> CORS(app, send_wildcard=True)

see [CORS API doc](http://flask-cors.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html) for more details

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess that you're browsing the test page on the `file://` domain (rather than via HTTP) - `file://` resources have limited support for CORS.

If you browse the test page on a web server then the CORS works as expected. For example you can run a command like this to start a simple PHP web server:

`php -S localhost:5001 ./test.html`

then access the page via the URL `http://localhost:5001/`

Comment: Thank you Matt, this is really helpful. I wonder what has changed in Chrome 65 to disallow the activity though.